# Difference between using WCF WsHttpBinding with certificate and HTTP with SSL

Tags: wcf, https, certificate

I am using wsHttpBidning with certificate authentication in my project. i understand the certificate is used to encrypt the date sent over the network and authentication as well.

how is it different from using HTTPS URL over SS. even here also we us certificate and only difference is it uses secured port for data communication.

Can someone explain me when should i use Https/SSL instead of HTTP with certificate?

Comment: It's quite simply a different protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Certificates can be used for different purposes. In your scenario (wsHttpBidning) it's used to authenticate the service to consumers. It's just identity check and has nothing to do with SSL. But for [SSL to work](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/SSL-Certificates-HOWTO/x64.html) you need a pair of asymmetric keys (used during SSL handshake to setup session symmetric key) and certificates are just containers for such keys.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I can configure my endpoint to encrypt with certificate , then it would be same as SSL?